# proc_open interaction

Tags: ssh, pipe, php, proc-open

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: open a shell (korn or bash, doesn't matter), from that shell, I want to open a ssh connection (`ssh user@host`). At some point it is likely to happen I will be prompted for either a password or I might be asked whether or not I'm sure I want to connect (offending keys).

Before anyone asks: yes, I am aware there is a plugin for ssh2 exec calls, but the servers I'm working on don't support it, and are unlikely to do so.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$desc = array(array('pipe','r'),array('pipe','w'));//used in all example code
$p = proc_open('ssh user@host',$desc,$pipes);
if(!is_resource($p)){ die('@!#$%');}//will omit this line from now on
sleep(1);//omitting this,too but it's there every time I need it
```

Then I tried to read console output (`stream_get_contents($pipes[1])`) to see what I have to pass next (either password, yes or return `'connection failed: '.stream_get_contents($pipes[1])` and proc_close $p.

This gave me the following error:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

So, I though ssh was called in the `php://` io-stream context, seems a plausible explanation of the above error.

Next: I though about [my first SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843550/load-profile-with-proc-open) and decided it might be a good idea to open a bash/ksh shell first:

```
$p = proc_open('bash',$desc,$pipes);
```

And take it from there, but I got the exact same error message, only this time, the script stopped running but ssh did run. So I got hopeful, then felt stupid and, eventually, desperate:

```
$p=proc_open('bash && ssh user@host',$desc,$pipes);
```

After a few seconds wait, I got the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133693440 bytes)

The Call Stack keeps bringing up the stream_get_contents line, even in my last desperate attempt:

```
#!/path/to/bin/php -n
<?php
    $p = proc_open('bash && ssh user@host',array(array('pipe','r'),array('pipe','w')),$ps);
    if (!is_resource($p))
    {
        die('FFS');
    }
    usleep(10);
    fwrite($ps[0],'yes'."\n");
    fflush($ps[0]);
    usleep(20);
    fwrite($ps[0],'password'."\n");
    fflush($ps[0]);
    usleep(20);
    fwrite($ps[0],'whoami'."\n");
    fflush($ps[0]);
    usleep(2);
    $msg = stream_get_contents($ps[1]);
    fwrite($ps[0],'exit'."\n");
    fclose($ps[0]);
    fclose($ps[1]);
    proc_close($p);
?>
```

I know, its a mess, a lot of `fflush` and redundancy, but the point is: I know this connection will first prompt me for offending keys, and then ask a password. My guess is the stream in $pipes[1] holds the ssh connection, hence it's content is huge. what I need then, is a pipe inside a pipe... is this even possible? I must be missing something, what good is a pipe if this isn't possible... 
My guess is the proc_open command is wrong to begin with, (error: Broken pipe). But I really can't see any other way around the first error... any thoughts? Or follow up questions if the above rant isn't at all clear (which it probably isn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before anyone asks: yes, I am aware there is a plugin for ssh2 exec
>   calls, but the servers I'm working on don't support it, and are
>   unlikely to do so.

There are actually two.  The PECL module, which is a PITA that most servers don't have installed anyway and [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  An example of its use:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting lib, though I wonder: is it still supported? judging by the code, I'd say it's written with PHP4 in mind, and the first bunch of hits on google are all over a year old... I'll give it a try, nonetheless. If it works, it works, and I'll let you know

Comment: There was a commit made three days ago to its SVN repo and the author made a post yesterday helping someone.  I think the goal of the library is to be both PHP4 and PHP5 compatible.  Using private / public instead of var makes the code PHP5 only but doesn't really add a lot otherwise imho.

Comment: Sorry, nice though this lib is, interacting with the processes on the remote host is still a bit of a no-no, isn't it? `$ssh->exec('su');` for example, will hang, because I can't seem to find a way to pass the password.

Comment: Try $ssh->read() and $ssh->write().  Here's an example of how to do it with sudo: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_sudo

Comment: Thanks... stupid of me not to spend 5 minutes more checking sourceforge. I'm still a bit worried about the successive calls, though... but hey, I'll get there. Thanks again

Comment: I've installed the pecl module phpseclib and it's shown on the phpinfo(), but i cant run that code. I've tried modifying some things, but still cannot run it.