# Java program runs differently from shell and with exec() in PHP

Tags: java, php, exec, shell-exec

I am running a Java program on a web server and passing it arguments that come from PHP variables, and I'm running into a bit of a confusing issue.  A Java program I am using seems to exhibit different behavior when I run it from shell and run it from shell_exec() in with PHP.

If I use a tool like Putty to execute the program from command line like so:

```
ksh runexample.ksh ClassName methodName
```

It runs properly, meaning the program sends a request and after about 20 seconds receives a response from gateway servers it connects to.  I am then able to see that the communication was successful by seeing the resulting record in an outside database.

Now the issue arises when I execute this program from a PHP script by using.

```
shell_exec('path/ssh user@xxx.xx.xxxx.xx.x "cd /path/path/examples/ ksh runexample.ksh ClassName methodName;')
```

If I load this PHP script, and var_dump() the output, the program seems to load; but it gives me a short generic message from the Java program like "program running in connected mode etc etc", and doesn't output the usual response.  The PHP script loads a page almost instantly with this output. Also, no record is created in the outside database.

I have set_time_limit(0) in the script, but could this issue be due to shell_exec() somehow timing out before the request/response in the Java program is complete?

Thanks for any insight/similar experiences, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be down to the fact that there is no (or another) `.profile` file loaded when running the application the way you do.

I've done something quite similar to what you seem to be be doing here, and ended up [posting this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102952/proc-open-interaction), as a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843550/load-profile-with-proc-open) both of which might be of use to you now.