# Result form crontab is not same as manually execute?

Tags: php, linux, shell, cron

I have a PHP script that execute some shell commands.

Once I manually executed it. It worked very fine.

But after I used crontab to execute, the result from some shell commands are missing.

These are 2 commands.

- `ip route`
- `iptables -t nat -L | grep 8800`

and here is a sample PHP code.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
    $route = exec('ip route');
    $iptable = exec('iptables -t nat -L | grep 8800');
    echo $route;
    echo $iptables;
?>
```

The above code worked well with manually execute but not crontab.

I found that some commands worked well with both. For example

- `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
- `cat /tmp/example | grep test`

Any ideas for this problem, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things worth noting:

The `exec` function's signature is

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

To get the full output of a command you'll have to call it like so:

```
$output = array();//declare in advance is best because:
$lastLine = exec('ip route', $status, $output);//signature shows reference expected
print_r($output);//full output, array, each index === new line
echo PHP_EOL, 'The command finished ', $status === 0 ? 'well' : 'With errors: '.$status;
```

You're using the `exec` command as though it were `passthru`, which might be worth a look in your case:

> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use [the passthru() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).

It's important to not that, when you run the command manually, it has access to all your environment variables, loaded when you log in (and any additional vars set in your `.profile` or `.basrc` file). This is not the case when running a command using crontab or over ssh.
Perhaps, the `$PATH` environment variable is set so, that you don't have access to `ip` and other commands. There are easy fixes for this:

```
exech('/sbin/ip route');//if that's the correct path
```

Or, have a second script at the ready, and change your PHP script to:

```
if (!exec('which ip'))
{//ip command not found
    return exec('helper.sh '.implode(' ', $argv));//helper script
}
```

With the helper script looking like this:

```
#/bin/bash
source /home/user/.bashrc
$*
```

Where `$*` merely calls the original PHP script again, only this time, the profile has been loaded. You could replace the `source` call with `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` or something, and just set the environment variables up the way you need them.

The third, and final part uses pipes, and [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/proc_open). It's a PHP-only way of loading the profile and calling the script recursively:

```
if(!$_SERVER['FOO'])
{//where FOO is an environment variable that is loaded in the .profile/.bashrc file
    $d = array(array('pipe','r'),array('pipe','w'));
    $p = proc_open('ksh',$d,$pipes);
    if(!is_resource($p) || end($argv) === 'CalledFromSelf')
    {//if the last argument is calledFromSelf, we've been here before, and it didn't work
        die('FFS');//this is to prevent deadlock due to infinite recursive self-calling
    }
    fwrite($pipes[0],'source /home/user/.profile'."\n");
    fwrite($pipes[0],implode(' ',$argv).' CalledFromSelf'."\n");
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    usleep(15);//as long as you need
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($p);
    exit();
}
echo $_SERVER['FOO'].PHP_EOL;//actual script goes here, we can use the FOO env var
```

This is how I solved [an old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843550/load-profile-with-proc-open) where I encountered difficulties with environment variables not being set

Last thing to note is: Does the user running crontab have the permissions required to do what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to what user runs the script. May be the user (which you add crontab task) haven't got enough permissions.

Comment: @Guilgamos: Perhaps, but which user is running the script? what group does it belong to? does it need `sudo` to run networking-related commands? That's not unlikely on a *NIX system, after all

Comment: if you run script in command line, the script work with current user permissions. If the script runs by crontab - with permission of the user which the crontab file belong to. Use crontab -l -u username to display crontab file fo some user